# How to use @XmlVariableNode in Jersey?

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

Found this example, exactly what I want: [MOXy's @XmlVariableNode - Using a Map's Key as the Node Name](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html), but tough luck using it in my Jersey 2.2 application.

`@XmlVariableNode("key")` on `MapAdapter.AdapterdMap.entry` is giving a compile error:

> XmlVariableNode cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason being `org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode` is only available in org.eclipse.persistence.moxy (EclipseLink Moxy) 2.5.1 and 2.6.0, which are only available in a nightly build at the moment.

To make it work with Jersey 2.2 which is using 2.5.0 of EclipseLink Moxy, use the following pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- To get early access to org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode -->
        <!-- TODO get rid of exclusion and use jersey.version=2.3 when it's released -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <!--<version>2.5.0</version>-->
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- To get early access to org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode -->
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

and you'll need the SNAPSHOT repository as well:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
        <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Please note that 2.5.1-RC1 is a [more] stable build, alternatively you can use 2.5.1-SNAPSHOT or 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT. For more info dependencies see

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven
- https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~org.eclipse.persistence.moxy

Whenever they release the next version, you can remove the snapshot/RC tag, to watch the news: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink; [the proposed 2.5.1 date is 27th September 2013](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/DevMeetings#Release_Planning)

According to [Jersey's Road Map](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3aroadmap-panel) 2.3 is coming out 23th September 2013, so it is impossible to include 2.5.1..., so maybe 2.4, until then ... wait for it ... dependency exclusion.